# Get distinct list of ids from another collection where array field contains id from item in current collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have multiple collections in the MongoDB database:

```
users: [{
  id: "name1",
  groups: ["group1"]
}, {
  id: "name2",
  groups: ["group2"]
}]

groups: [{
  id: "group1",
  name: "first group"
}, {
  id: "group2",
  name: "second group"
}, {
  id: "group3",
  name: "third group"
}]
```

I want to get all the records from the `groups` collections, but also want to add an `assignedTo` field to each record in the response that contains a list of ids of users that belong to the group:

```
[{
  id: "group1",
  name: "first group",
  assignedTo: ["user1"]
}, {
  id: "group2",
  name: "second group"
  assignedTo: ["user2"]
}, {
  id: "group3",
  name: "third group"
  assignedTo: []
}]
```

How can I do it using the aggregation framework? Thanks

P.S. A group may not have assigned users, but it is still required to be shown in the response as

```
[
...
{
  id: "group3",
  name: "third group",
  assignedTo: [] # empty array
}]
```

Comment: users is collection of users , or user item is array ?

Comment: Users is a separate collection as well as groups, and each user has a list of the groups it belongs to

Answer (score 0):

`$lookup` add group data to users

`$unwind` destruct groups array

`$group` create an array by groups

`$project` finalize data as we need

```
db.collection('users').aggregate(
[
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'groups', 
      'localField': 'groups', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'groups'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$groups'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'id': '$groups._id', 
        'name': '$groups.name'
      }, 
      'assignedTo': {
        '$addToSet': '$$ROOT._id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'id': '$_id.id', 
      'name': '$_id.name', 
      'assignedTo': 1, 
      '_id': 0
    }
  }
]
)
```

Comment: I assume if a group does not have any users assigned to it, it will not be shown, right? I have updated the question

Comment: we populate groups from users collection , so it's impossible to have docs that don't have `assignedTo`